# Context Menu on Tree in GWT 2.0.3

Tags: gwt

GWT 2.0.3 
Feature :

1. it's not allow to select the tree using right click.

I am try to use the Context menu on tree or TreeItem using 
onBrowserEvent event. 
but there is no TreeItem is selected on right click of treeitem.

how to achieve the context menu features in GWT 2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks i got the solution. we can override the onBrowserEvent method and enabled the right click on GWT Tree